# How to quickFix all in VS code (typescript)

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, ide

I have searched in VS code for a quick fix all solution and can't find anything on the docs or plugins. Does this feature simply not exist or is there a keybinding I'm missing out on? (currently using typescript support)

Edit:

just clarifying use case:

quick fix all like fix all whitespace / "" instead of '' and no semicolon warnings.

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using tslint plugin:

In [`keybindings.json`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_advanced-customization)

```
{
    "key": "",
    "command": "editor.action.codeAction",
    "args": {
        "kind": "source.fixAll.tslint",
        "apply": "first"
    }
},
```